# Null point of an electric field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vector-fields

For opposite charges, why is the null point ($E_{\text{net}}= 0$) of an electric field closer to the smaller charge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the place where there is no resultant force.

1. For charges of equal signs:

Let's imagine moving on a line from the larger to the smaller charge.

The larger charge provides a bigger force, but it falls of as an inverse square law as we go further away from it.    The force from the smaller charge gets larger as we come closer to it.

Half way between, the force from the larger charge is still larger, but there will be a point past half way, where the force from each charge balances.  At that point the electric field is zero.

2. For charges of opposite signs:

The resultant force is zero at a point nearer the smaller charge (in magnitude), but at a point not between the charges.  That way the distance to the small charge can be smaller than the distance to the big charge and from arguments similar to 1) the forces can balance.